Oracle APEX app static CSS/JS files URL on Multiple DADs
I am learning Oracle Architecture for APEX setup. I posted similar post but I believe I did not explain myself well for that and I am trying to post it with different explanation.
Databases accounts setup
Let us say we have HR data residing under HR_DATA schema and
ACCOUNTING data residing under ACCOUNTING_DATA schema.
We have HR_USER and ACCOUNTING_USER and it is required to use HR_USER to access HR_DATA and ACCOUNTING_USER to access ACCOUNTING_DATA.
All of the above data and accounts are in one oracle database.
APEX setup
We have one APEX workspace called APEX_WORKSPACE and want to build APEX apps for both HR and ACCOUNTING.
APEX is setup with DAD called /DEFAULT to access APEX app.
So, the URL to access to APEX app looks like the following.
https://hostname/ords/default/f?p=100
We have some CSS/JS files which are uploaded to Static Application Files and we are referencing them
At page level with #APP_FILES#MAIN.CSS.
So, far at this level, those CSS/JS files were loaded and work fine.
Our thought
We will create two DADs/Connection pools with based paths such as /HR   and /ACCOUNTING where
/HR will use HR_USER as DB_USER and
/ACCOUNTING will use ACCOUNTING_USER as DB_USER.
Remark: we are trying to connect to a single database with multiple DADs/Connection pool.
Problem
We try to access APEX App with new Dads.
/DEFAULT         DAD: https://hostname/ords/default/f?p=100         - it works fine, CSS/JS files loaded.
/HR              DAD: https://hostname/ords/hr/f?p=100              - CSS/JS files – 404 not found error
/ACCOUNTING      DAD: https://hostname/ords/accounting/f?p=100      - CSS/JS files – 404 not found error
When I tried to get the actual URL of exact CSS file for /HR and /ACCOUNTING, here are the followings.
https://hostname/ords/hr/apex_workspace/r/100/files/static/v9/MAIN.CSS
https://hostname/ords/accounting/apex_workspace/r/100/files/static/v9/MAIN.CSS
If I replaced /HR or /ACCOUNTING with /DEFAULT for above URLs, it definitely works.
Here are some alternatives we found on research:
•   Using CDN: our company doesn’t really allow outbound connections.
•   Loading working URL for CSS files to APEX APP property/interface.
The approach with this is that every time we promote apex app from DEV to TEST or TEST to PROD, we have to change the hostname at URL links. Is there a way we can change CSS/JS file URL dynamically?
•   Having Webserver setup internally for these CSS/JS files (might not be cost-effective).
Questions:
Is there any fix we can do so new DADs can point to the right URL for the CSS file?
What is the connection between Oracle DAD path and APEX APP Static files?
Is this related to ORDS or APEX?
Is there any alternative solution which can fits to our needs which can be also cost-effective?
Thanks for your help! Any recommendation is appreciated.


From your description it looks like you're trying to map the "old" way of pl/sql gateway connecting to the database through a DAD to APEX. I don't think the approach you are suggesting is workable, because "that is not how APEX works". With the pl/sql gateway, the HR user would connect to the database through the "HR" dad and the ACCOUNTING user would connect to the database through the "ACCOUNTING" dad. For APEX that is different. APEX always connects as APEX_PUBLIC_USER and then, depending on the schema that is linked to the workspace, does an "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA" to switch to the actual schema context.
The "normal" way to tackle your requirement is to have a workspace for HR and a workspace for ACCOUNTING and that's it. No additional "DAD" needed. ORDS will handle the connection pooling for you - no need to worry about that.

Thanks alot @koen Lostrie  for your reply. Could you please explain a bit on how we can set up one workspace to use HR user and another workspace to use ACCOUNTING user. We know how to create a workspace but just not on connecting workspace and database user. Thanks alot!

schema's are assigned to workspaces. When you create a workspace, you have to assign a schema to it. If you want, you can add more than one schema to a workspace. Typically you have one workspace and multiple schemas. In your example, you could have a single workspace and assign HR an ACCOUNTING

Or you could have 2 separate workspace. In my opinion, that is only needed if HR and ACCOUNTING are 2 completely separate dev teams within the company. If you have the same developers working on both, it makes more sense to have a single workspace with 2 schemas.
But... I'd say: play with it and try it out :)

Thanks a lot for the explanation! It really changed my way of thinking and it solved puzzles we had.
